# Rust: Implement AVL Tree and error: thread 'main' panicked at 'already borrowed: BorrowMutError'

Tags: rust, avl-tree

I have the following tree structure:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cmp;
use std::cmp::Ordering;

type AVLTree<T> = Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode<T>>>>;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone)]
struct TreeSet<T: Ord> {
    root: AVLTree<T>,
}

impl<T: Ord> TreeSet<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { 
            root: None 
        }
    }

    fn insert(&mut self, value: T) -> bool {
        let current_tree = &mut self.root;

        while let Some(current_node) = current_tree {

            let node_key = &current_node.borrow().key;
          
            match node_key.cmp(&value) {
                Ordering::Less => { let current_tree = &mut current_node.borrow_mut().right; },
                Ordering::Equal => {
                    return false;
                }
                Ordering::Greater => { let current_tree = &mut current_node.borrow_mut().left; },
            }
        }

        *current_tree = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode {
            key: value,
            left: None,
            right: None,
            parent: None
        })));

        true
    }

}


#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq)]
struct TreeNode<T: Ord> {
    pub key: T,
    pub parent: AVLTree<T>,
    left: AVLTree<T>,
    right: AVLTree<T>,
}


fn main() {
    let mut new_avl_tree: TreeSet<u32> = TreeSet::new();
    new_avl_tree.insert(3);
    new_avl_tree.insert(5);
    println!("Tree: {:#?}", &new_avl_tree);
}
```

Building with `cargo build` is fine, but when I run `cargo run`, I got the below error:

> thread 'main' panicked at 'already borrowed: BorrowMutError', src\libcore\result.rs:1165:5
>
> note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace. error: process didn't
>
> exit successfully: `target\debug\avl-tree.exe` (exit code: 101)

If i just call `insert(3)`, it will be fine and my tree gets printed correctly. However, if I `insert(5)` after `insert(3)`, I will get that error.

How do I fix that?

Comment: There is a logic problem in your code: `let current_tree = ...` creates a new local variable. Yet the algorithm could only work if `current_tree` is reassigned in the loop. If you initialize `current_tree` as `mut` and remove the `let` at the reassignments, then the compile errors will show up. Yet this was the easy part.

Answer (score 3):

Manually implementing data structures such as linked list, tree, graph are not task for novices, because of memory safety rules in language. I suggest you to read [Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/index.html) tutorial, which discusses how to implement safe and unsafe linked lists in Rust right way.

Also read about [name shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).
Your error is that inside a cycle you try to borrow mutable something which is already borrowed as immutable.

```
let node_key = &current_node.borrow().key; // Borrow as immutable

match node_key.cmp(&value) {
    Ordering::Less => { let current_tree = &mut current_node.borrow_mut().right; }, // Create a binding which will be immediately deleted and borrow as mutable.
```

And I recommend you to read [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) to learn rust.

Answer (score 2):

First let us correct your algorithm. The following lines are incorrect:

```
let current_tree = &mut current_node.borrow_mut().right;
...
let current_tree = &mut current_node.borrow_mut().left;
```

Both do not reassign a value to `current_tree` but create a new (unused) one (@Inline refers to it as Name shadowing). Remove the `let` and make `current_tree` `mut`.

Now we get a compiler error `temporary value dropped while borrowed`. Probably the compiler error message did mislead you. It tells you to use `let` to increase the lifetime, and this would be right if you used the result in the same scope, but no let can increase the lifetime beyond the scope.

The problem is that you cannot pass out a reference to a value owned by a loop (as `current_node.borrow_mut.right`). So it would be better to use `current_tree` as owned variable. Sadly this means that many clever tricks in your code will not work any more.

Another problem in the code is the multiple borrow problem (your original runtime warning is about this). You cannot call `borrow()` and `borrow_mut()` on the same `RefCell` without panic(that is the purpose of `RefCell`).

So after finding the problems in your code, I got interested in how I would write the code. And now that it is written, I thought it would be fair to share it:
    fn insert(&mut self, value: T) -> bool {
      if let None = self.root {
        self.root = TreeSet::root(value);
        return true;
      }
      let mut current_tree = self.root.clone();

```
  while let Some(current_node) = current_tree {
    let mut borrowed_node = current_node.borrow_mut();
    match borrowed_node.key.cmp(&value) {
      Ordering::Less => {
        if let Some(next_node) = &borrowed_node.right {
          current_tree = Some(next_node.clone());
        } else {
          borrowed_node.right = current_node.child(value);
          return true;
        }
      }
      Ordering::Equal => {
        return false;
      }
      Ordering::Greater => {
        if let Some(next_node) = &borrowed_node.left {
          current_tree = Some(next_node.clone());
        } else {
          borrowed_node.left = current_node.child(value);
          return true;
        }
      }
    };
  }
  true
}

//...

trait NewChild<T: Ord> {
  fn child(&self, value: T) -> AVLTree<T>;
}
impl<T: Ord> NewChild<T> for Rc<RefCell<TreeNode<T>>> {
  fn child(&self, value: T) -> AVLTree<T> {
    Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(TreeNode {
      key: value,
      left: None,
      right: None,
      parent: Some(self.clone()),
    })))
  }
}
```

One will have to write the two methods `child(value:T)` and `root(value:T)` to make this compile.

Comment: thanks for your detailed response. If I understand you correct, `Treeset::root` will just creates a new `Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode<T>>>>` ? What does `current_node.child(value)` do? Its type is `Rc<RefCell<TreeNode<T>>>`. How to implement this function for `Rc`?

Comment: You are right. The original implementation did not set the parent. That means, that `child(parent:Rc<RefCell<TreeNode<T>>>, value:T)` would be a proper signature. The rest is syntactical sugar - I added it now.

Comment: I tried this, and the code runs without stopping. There might be a circular reference somewhere.

Comment: The problem is your `println!("Tree: {:#?}", &new_avl_tree);`. You will have to implement `Display` or `Debug` and exclude `the parent field from been displayed. Otherwise `parent` produces the circular reference (as you observe it).